# When divs don't resize with content?

Tags: css

I'm working on some complex design and have a silly question once again :)

Well, let's say I have a div and some content inside, like:

```
<div style="background-color: #fff; width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;">
     <img src="img.png" />
     <p>Blablabla :)</p>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #000; width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

Div's width is fixed, but I don't tell the browser what's the height (so there's no height property of div in css file).

And then, when I add more and more text the first paragraph or bigger image, the text-child of first div is in the second div.

How to prevent this from happening? Or what did I to make it happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are not using position as absolute on second div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the parent divs are not `position:absolute;` or `position:fixed;` in the CSS. They should be `position:relative;`.

If any child items are `float:left;` or `float:right;` then the reective parent div needs an `overflow:auto;` property inorder to cause the div to *fully* wrap the child items.

It'd help us help you more if you posted a whole sample of a working page, not just the divs, and the CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

It should be auto-expanding, it sounds like you have some *other* styling with positioning that's throwing the default behavior off.

[You can see in a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/phmFa/) that it should expand (`height: auto;`) to whatever content you give it, dynamically added or not.

Comment: Ok, but what kinds of styling change this behavior off? I guess floats, anything else?

Comment: @fomicz - Or the `position` style being `fixed` or `absolute`...there are a few ways to get this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I would check for floats and positioning on the img and p. But I cant tell you more without seeing the full css/html can you post a link?